# How to enable USB 2.0 in Virtualbox 4.0.10, option for enabling EHCI is missing

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, debian, usb-2

I'm using Virtualbox 4.0.10 under Debian stable with Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack 4.0.18r82821 to host an MS-Windows XP virtual machine for embedded software development.

Unfortunately the VM option Settings -> USB -> "Enable USB2 (EHCI) Controller" doesn't show up, and the Windows guest only sees USB 1.1 (OHCI).  USB 1.1 works, but is of course quite slow.

I have a hunch that the reason is that my machine (a Thinkpad T420s) has USB 3.0, but I couldn't find any info despite searching quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to properly pass USB3 ports (even with USB2 devices attached) into a VBox VM... Try a straight USB2 port if you have any.

Comment: I can't enable USB 2.0 for the whole virtual machine, so I don't think it works on any port.

Comment: In that case, Have you followed the guide on Linux USB support? https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#ts_usb-linux

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. I'm in group `vboxusers`, and I don't think I have an older system (`usbfs` is not used in my system).